Pact file publishing error: can_i_deploy_long_desc.txt not found in pact-workshop-js (Step 11)
I am working through the pact-workshop-js tutorial. In Step 11, after testing the consumer and trying to publish the pact file, I encounter the following error:

C:/pact-workshop-js/consumer/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/standalone/windows-x64-2.0.3/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/pact_broker-client-1.68.0/lib/pact_broker/client/cli/matrix_commands.rb:9:in
`read': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen


C:/pact-workshop-js/consumer/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-core/standalone/windows-x64-2.0.3/pact/lib/vendor/ruby/3.2.0/gems/pact_broker-client-1.68.0/lib/pact_broker/client/cli/can_i_deploy_long_desc.txt (Errno::ENOENT)

The error suggests that the file can_i_deploy_long_desc.txt is missing. I am using the same Node.js version and pact libraries as my friend, and they can successfully publish the pact file on their machine.
What I’ve tried:

Reinstalling dependencies (npm install after deleting node_modules and package-lock.json).
Checking file permissions on the node_modules folder.
Disabling antivirus to ensure no files are being quarantined.
Testing on different Node.js versions, but the issue persists.
Comparing my setup with my friend's setup, but couldn't find any significant differences.

Environment:
OS: Windows 11
Node.js: v20.17.0 (same as friend)
pact-broker-client: same as pact-workshop-js

i try add @pact-foundation/pact-cli v16.0.1 and the error is change to
did_you_mean' was not loaded. C:/Users/m/pact-workshop-js/consumer/node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-cli-windows-x64/standalone/windows-x64-2.4.14/pact/lib/ruby/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:75:in require': cannot load such file -- pact_broker/client/cli/custom_thor (LoadError)
